# Can not install libnuma-dev on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, numa

I installed libnuma-dev by:

```
sudo apt-get install libnuma-dev
```

But I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libnuma-dev : Depends: libnuma1 (= 2.0.8~rc3-1) but 2.0.9~rc5-1ubuntu3.14.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried uninstall and re-install, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: sounds like Ubuntu's package repositories are broken, once again. anyway, Ubuntu 14.04? Is that *really* necessary in the year 2017? From all long-term-releasing distros, imho, Ubuntu is the one to age the worst, so, I'd strongly recommend updating to 16.04.

Comment: so, the problem is the version Ubuntu, right?

Comment: well, to be honest, it seems there's a problem with the quality of ubuntu's release engineering, but that is a general beef I have with Canonical, and really not the point we should be discussing. updating Ubuntu is a very fine solution, here.

Comment: Did you try to upgrade your system? I afraid of losing data.

Comment: You have backups, I hope, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Update your system to the latest version. This is what causes the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade `libnuma1` to the latest version. It's set up to require the exact same `-dev` package version, and the one corresponding to the base package you currently have installed is apparently no longer available.